# smart contract payout scheme

Tags: transactions, contract-design, smart-contract-wallets

recently I found myself working on a project that might just be perfectly suited to attach a token model to.
For this to work, however, I need some knowledge on the feasibility of one of the aspects.
One aspect would have to be that the token's smart contract acts as the storage of a "community pool" of X tokens.
Each month a fixed share of this pool is to be paid out to active community members.
This is where the complications come into play because the data collection on members' activity is stored and evaluated off-chain, on a conventional server.
As far as I understand it, I could theoretically use the payload data in ERC777 to send data in such a way that a mapping performed, however, this is hardly scalable as it would have to contain hundreds or more likely even thousands of mappings.

On the other hand, there used to exist a token called COSS (later renamed to COS) that had a similar model.
It was basically a crypto exchange that offered token holders a share of the exchange fees, paid out at the end of every month.

Sadly, I am at my wits end on how to realize such an implementation and would be grateful for any help or resources pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: You could make the evaluation off-chain, and just send the result to the contract. Address a1, receives x1 percentage, a2 receives x2, and so on.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for the response.
While this is definitely possible and probably the easiest solution, it would cost a lot of gas fees to save all that data to the network.
I'd prefer another solution.
Another user suggested EDSCA signed messages, what do you think about that?

Comment: I've never heard about EDSCA, do you have a link about EDSCA? For large data an approach is to have a merkle tree with accounts and balances, you only commit the root to the contract and each participant can make the claim. Have you thought about using a layer 2 solution?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was talking about ECDSA of course: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/cryptography#ECDSA
Merkle trees are a similar cryptographic approach as far as I understand it. However, I don't quite understand how this would work for my use case.

I actually hadn't read much about layer 2 at all so far, thanks for the hint.
However, I also feel like this wouldn't be a sensible approach for my specific use case. I do want to stay on the ETH mainnet and realize this as an ERC777 token